# Sharing non-layout templates between apps using Meteor

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

I have two meteor apps. Each one has a smart-package that implements a certain  feature, lets say user management, in an app-specific way. I also have a third meteor smart package that lives in a *shared* package directory. This third package has user management templates that are common to both apps. I use iron-router.

I need to combine the shared templates with the app templates. Iron-Router has the `yield` keyword. This is useful for combining templates. The problem is that this only works for special, nominated layout templates.

How do you combine, or nest, templates that are not layout templates using meteor and iron-router?

### Example

In the simplified example below you can see three packages and their corresponding templates. The `app-*:user` packages implement app specific user templates and the `shared:user` package implements a shared user template.

#### app-1:users

**appUser.tpl.jade**

```
p This is some App-1 specific text
```

---

#### app-2:users

**appUser.tpl.jade**

```
p This is some App-2 specific text
```

---

#### shared:users

**user.tpl.jade**

```
h1 This is a shared title
+appUser
```

**routes.coffee**

```
Router.route '/user', name: 'user'
```

The problem here is that the nested template *must* be called `appUser` in both the dependent smart packages. This not only prevents the templates name being appropriately descriptive for the app but, more worryingly, tightly couples the template name and makes for fragile code.

It is to prevent this tight coupling of templates that iron-router allows us to use the `yield` keyword, but since we cannot use the `yield` keyword in this context (can we?) then I am left wondering if this truly is the only way to implement shared templates?

Comment: What is a *non-layout template*? Meteor templates are by definition HTML/blaze.

Comment: With iron-router certain templates can be designated as [layout templates](https://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#layouts). Such templates can take advantage of the `yield` keyword to dynamically include route specific detail templates. A _non-layout template_ is a template that has not been so designated and therefore cannot use the `yield` keyword.

Comment: Blaze templates are really all the same, if there's a `{{> yield}}` then it can be used as the parameter to `layoutTemplate:` in i-r. Any template can nest another one directly with `{{> templateName }}` without using i-r. So what exactly are you trying to do? Can you show code and what's not working?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I have added an example. I hope that makes things clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to benefit from [dynamic templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic). These are templates whose name can be passed in via a helper (defined globally or tied to the parent template) and whose data context can even be set by a helper.

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=myTemplate [data=myData] }}
```

Your code supplies `myTemplate` and `myData` dynamically here and the kerbobble (html, helpers, event handlers) then gets stuffed into the parent template.